# audio sample frequency pitch

Tags: c++, audio, frequency, pitch

Im trying to find out how to change the pitch of a block of samples.
So far ive been using the smbPitchShift code yet but someone told me pitch shifting can be done in a simple conversion of frequency.

Say right now i have a block of 2000 samples running at frequency 44100hz.
How do i manage to shift the pitch by 2 octaves up (24 semitones) ?
This guy told its just a conversion of 1/frequency, which i dont really understand.

Its a VST plugin im trying to develop in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the tempo, or are you OK with it running 4x faster?

Comment: No i need to keep the tempo, basically staying always at 2000 samples like the input.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as simple as it sounds...

if you do not need to keep the formants one way is time stretch 4x your sample and at the end resample (interpolate) by 4, this step pitch shift your audio.

To strech you usually need some pitch track algorithm, in time domain some know codes are PSOLA, WSOLA, TDHS, SOLA, VSOLA...

To strech in frequency domain you can use phase vocoder.

Remember without formants will produce Demon/chipmunk effect.